Why does my Calendar overlay view not working properly?
so I created a a popover input field for my project, the other inputs are working properly but when I tried to use CalendarPicker from shadcn, the opacity of calendar becomes zero wherein the background of the calendar is transparent. I tried copying directly from shadcn docs but its just the same.




const CreateTransactionDialog = ({ trigger, type }: Props) => {

    return (
        <Dialog>
            <DialogTrigger asChild>{trigger}</DialogTrigger>
            <DialogContent>
 
                <Form {...form}>
                    <form className="space-y-4">

                       .../other input fields
                        <div className="flex items-center justify-between gap-2">
                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="date"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
                                        <FormLabel>Transaction</FormLabel>
                                        <Popover>
                                            <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                                                <FormControl>
                                                    <Button
                                                        variant={"outline"}
                                                        className={cn(
                                                            "w-[240px] pl-3 text-left font-normal",
                                                            !field.value && "text-muted-foreground"
                                                        )}
                                                    >
                                                        {field.value ? (
                                                            format(field.value, "PPP")
                                                        ) : (
                                                            <span>Pick a date</span>
                                                        )}
                                                        <CalendarIcon className="ml-auto h-4 w-4 opacity-50" />
                                                    </Button>
                                                </FormControl>
                                            </PopoverTrigger>
                                            <PopoverContent className="w-auto opacity-100 p-0" align="start">
                                                <Calendar
                                                    mode="single"
                                                    selected={field.value}
                                                    onSelect={field.onChange}
                                                  
                                                    initialFocus
                                                />
                                            </PopoverContent>
                                        </Popover>
                                        <FormDescription>
                                           Transaction Date
                                        </FormDescription>
                                        <FormMessage />
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />
                        </div>

                        
                    </form>
                </Form>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    )
}

export default CreateTransactionDialog

